# Oracle SQL query to do Interpolation In Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, interpolation

[Interpolated results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDIVI.png)

Dear Experts,
I have interpolated values for AddOn correctly ( highlighted in yellow) using the analytic functions regr_slope and regr_intercept with the script below

```
with CLP_ADDON_CALC_STG (addon_product, term_years, underlying_term_years, addon) as
( SELECT 'CCREPO', 0.5, 5 , 0.0447 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCREPO', 0.5, 10 , 0.0516 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCREPO', 0.7, 9 , NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCREPO', 1, 5 , 0.0567 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CCREPO', 1, 10 , 0.0487 FROM DUAL)
,ordered_input_1 as (
SELECT
    i.*,
    row_number() over ( partition by addon_product order by term_years) rn
  FROM CLP_ADDON_CALC_STG i where (underlying_term_years < 9 or ( term_years < 0.7 and term_years > 0.7))
  or (term_years = 0.7 and underlying_term_years = 9)order by term_years, underlying_term_years
 -- where i.term_years 
)
SELECT 
 addon_product,
  term_years,
  underlying_term_years,
  addon, 
  term_years * regr_slope(addon, term_years) over ( partition by addon_product) +
       regr_intercept(addon, term_years) over ( partition by addon_product)
    as interpolated_value
FROM ordered_input_1
ORDER BY addon_product, term_years;
```

Now I am in situation where in I have to do interpolation on the interpolated values derived above for which I am not able to arrange the rows in order as required for the above analytic function. 
I had referred to this link to get the rows in order ( [Linear Interpolation in Oracle with special cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596147/linear-interpolation-in-oracle-with-special-cases))
But for the next round of interpolation for which I would need the rows in some order 
or I would need to a query (on the rows as seen in the image interpolated results ) which would do something like the below formula
`((9-5)*0.05364 + (10-9)*0.0463)/(10-5)` which would give me `0.052712`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance,
Murali

Comment: Any suggestions??